# ASP.NET 5, EF 7 and SQLite - compiler error CS1061

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a ASP.NET 5 project in VS 2015 (Beta 8) that includes EF 7 which is working on Full-CLR but not Core-CLR.  Below is the partial configuration:

```
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "EntityFramework.SQLite": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "EntityFramework.SQLite.Design": "7.0.0-beta8"
}

services.AddEntityFramework()
    .AddSqlite();
```

When using the above and publishing to Docker I get the following error:

> DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS1061: 'EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder' does
>   not contain a definition for 'AddSqlite' and no extension method
>   'AddSqlite' accepting a first argument of type
>   'EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder' could be found.

If I remove the EntityFramework.SQLite.Design dependency it then works.  I understand that EF 7 is still in beta and that the SQLite provider is incomplete, but is there a workaround?  I don't plan to use migrations in Linux.

**UPDATE**

I was thinking that I could create an extension method to ensure a successful compilation, but this class wasn't recognized.

```cs
#if DNXCORE50
public static class SqliteEntityServicesBuilderExtensions
{
    public static EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder AddSqlite(
        this EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder services)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: The inclusion of "EntityFramework.SQLite.Design" shouldn't affect the declaration of `AddSqlite()`. You may have more luck posting a bug to the EF project on github.com/aspnet/entityframework. (Please include a full repro project and your project.lock.json).

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3779

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft found a bug concerning case-sensitive package names.

Changing the dependency from `EntityFramework.SQLite.Design` to `EntityFramework.Sqlite.Design` resolved the issue.