# Adding SQLite in ASP.Net Core RC2

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.Net Core RC2 `net461` application that I would like to use SQLite with.

There is now a provider for this:

[image: Sqlite Core Provider]

I have verified my `project.json` file looks correct:

[image: project.json]

However, it can't see it in the `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup.cs`:

[image: Can't see Sqlite]

I must be missing something obvious here, any ideas?

The is [another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750255/asp-net-5-ef-7-and-sqlite-compiler-error-cs1061) that mentions it, but that is a different issue I believe.  I think Microsoft has resolved the case sensitivity issue, and I'm not dealing with a Sqlite designer.

Comment: Have you tried "dotnet restore" on the command prompt?

Comment: One thing that worked for me was to type/ erase something on the project.json and save it,  so the packages was restored again

Comment: Also please don't use the tag-like notation in question titles. See Help Center on usage of tags: http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging **You should not force a tag into your title.** and **The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title.**

Comment: @Tseng Not sure I follow ... what is the difference here between what I put ("Adding SQLite in ASP.Net Core RC2") and the edit ("ASP.Net Core RC2 - Adding SQLite").  Priority left-to-right?

Comment: This: "The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title.". Making a question title a list of tags won't help you get an answer faster. There is already a tag section for this and most people monitor the tags they are interested in (i.e. I am watching the asp.net-core tags and mvvm), so people will be able to find your question w/o a list of tags like "ASP.NET Core RC2 - Identity - Create User" or something similar. Your question won't become more visible with tags stuffed in the title and it's not natural to read

Comment: @Tseng Ok thanks.  I generally only do that with the new stuff because asp-net may have 5000 people while aspnet-core could have 50 because they simply haven't gotten around to adding the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was, it seems, a documentation issue with too many code samples showing the usage of AddSqlite() when in fact this needs to be done through the `DbContextOptionsBuilder` class.

So:

```
    services
        .AddEntityFramework()
        .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
            options =>
            { options.UseSqlite(connection); });
```

As an alternative, you can override the OnConfiguring method in MyDbContext:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connection);
    }
```